# What's the difference between a multiprocessor and a multiprocessing system?

Tags: parallel-processing, multi-processor

I'm studying IPC for a simple test I have tomorrow. The book my classroom uses is not the best: it makes a lot of typos and its exercises have been proven wrong or terribly ambiguous more than once.

This may not be the specific case, but I'm struggling trying to answer this question in the book:

> The parallelism of the execution of concurrent processes is...
>
> a) only virtual
> b) only real
> c) real on multiprocessing systems and virtual on multiprocessor systems
> d) real on multiprocessor systems and virtual on multiprocessing systems
> e) none of the above

I'm torn between answer c and d; what's the difference between multiprocessing and multiprocessor?

I've searched for an answer, but apparently both terms refer to the same thing.

This may seem a very dumb question but I'd like to know if they're actually the same thing or if they refer to different things in this context.

Comment: I would read `d` as implicitly having "that are not multiprocessor" on the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer would be D.

Multiprocessing presumably means it can handle multiple requests at once, which can be done on a single processor by sharing its time between tasks.

Multiprocessor implies that there is more than one processor (or at least more then 1 core on a processor) - where each core is actually its own processor, but combined on a single physical chip - the point being tasks can each be assigned a separate processor/core and can run concurrently.

This is a shockingly bad question and I would not expect the term multiprocessing to come up much in the real world.

Comment: I think this answer confuses "multiprocessing" with "multitasking".  The question (the book one OP asks about) is simply terrible.

Comment: @BenVoight I respectfully disagree about confusion. I did say "multiple requests" rather then "multiple programs" or "multiple jobs" - although we are agreed it's a bad question. Feel free to write a better answer though.